# "Can't you?" or "won't you?" at the end of a conditional sentence

Tags: conditionals, tag-questions

Can you tell me which one is correct?

A) If you try using true watercolors, you will find that you have to be very careful because you cannot cover up your mistakes, ***can't*** you?

B) If you try using true watercolors, you will find that you have to be very careful because you cannot cover up your mistakes, ***won't*** you?

Comment: you cannot....can you? you will not...will you? you haven't...have you? you shouldn't...should you? etc.

Comment: "You will find... won't you?" but "You cannot cover up your mistakes, can you?"

Answer (score 1):

The key things to remember in a 'statement, question'  construction of this kind is that the verbs in the statement and question must match (e.g. will... won't, can...can't, do...don't), the tenses must be the same, and the verb in the question is negative if the statement verb is positive, and vice versa:

> You **can** *(positive)* eat mushrooms, **can't** *(negative)* you?
>
> You **can't** eat coal *(negative)*, **can** *(positive)* you?
>
> You **will** wait for me, **won't** you?
>
> You **won't** be late, **will** you?
>
> You **didn't** kill my dog, **did** you?
>
> He **did** lock the door, **didn't** he?

Answer (score 0):

"B" is correct, and "A" is incorrect, but the conditional has very little to do with it.  The actual key part of the sentence is "...you will find..." which has to match the end.  Alternatively, you could change sentence "A" so that it reads:

> If you try using true watercolors, you ***can*** find that you have to be very careful because you cannot cover up your mistakes, ***can't*** you?

Note that this carries a slightly different meaning than sentence B.  "Will" is much more certain than "can".